# Upload file in S3 using Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

**Installation Process**

**[I followed this tutorial to install aws Package in Laravel 5.3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel)**

**My Code is below**

```
$s3 = \App::make('aws')->createClient('s3');

$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'Bucket_Name',
    'Key'        => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    'SourceFile' => 'http://domainname/sample.txt',
));
```

I am trying a txt file with around 50 bytes contents and got below error.

> A sha256 checksum could not be calculated for the provided upload
>   body, because it was not seekable. To prevent this error you can
>   either 1) include the ContentMD5 or ContentSHA256 parameters with your
>   request, 2) use a seekable stream for the body, or 3) wrap the
>   non-seekable stream in a GuzzleHttp\Psr7\CachingStream object. You
>   should be careful though and remember that the CachingStream utilizes
>   PHP temp streams. This means that the stream will be temporarily
>   stored on the local disk.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SourceFile` must be a local file path. The `Body` parameter allows stream, so you should be able to do a request with guzzle and pass the body to it.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://domainname/sample.txt');

$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'Bucket_Name',
    'Key' => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    'Body' => $response->getBody(),
]);
```